# PIG aggregate function - OutOfMemory: Java Heap Space

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

The following fails:

```
data = FOREACH rawData GENERATE (int) col;
aggregate = FOREACH data GENERATE MIN(col);
```

Is there somehow I can get it the above to work?

I tried this:

```
data = FOREACH rawData GENERATE 1 dummy, (int) col;
grouped = GROUP data BY dummy;
aggregate = FOREACH grouped GENERATE MIN(data.col)
```

Now I get a: `java.lang.Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

There are literally 11 rows of integers (1..11)...so not sure why I'm getting an outOfMemoryError?

I'm running the script from the command line `pig -f myscript.pig`

New to PIG so if I need to set something pls let me know...

Comment: Can you paste the stack track of this exception? By the way, you can use "group something all". For example, `data = FOREACH rawData(int) GENERATE col; grouped = GROUP data All; aggregate = FOREACH grouped GENERATE MIN(data.col)`

Comment: @zsxwing I was using the HBaseStorage loader, and I saw on the console: io.sort.mb 100.  I saw somewhere that would cause heap-error, so I add the following to the script: set io.sort.mb 10; and now it works fine.  Although not sure what impact this setting will have once I push my script into prod.

Comment: `io.sort.mb 100` is very low. I do not think set it to 10 is a good idea. It seems you does not configure any JVM memory parameters for your hadoop cluster. You need to increase `mapred.map.child.java.opts` and `mapred.reduce.child.java.opts` in `mapred-site.xml`, for example, set them to `-Xmx512M` or `-Xmx1024M`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition was correct in that you need to group the data first, before using `MIN`. You can use `GROUP ALL` for this purpose:

```
data = FOREACH rawData GENERATE (int) col;
grouped = GROUP data ALL;
aggregate = FOREACH grouped GENERATE MIN($1);
```

After a `GROUP` operation, `$0` contains the group, `$1` the first column, `$2` the second column, and so on.